# Is "float.is_integer() " only working with integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

[Here is a screen shot of run of "is.integer()" in Python 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iihXi.png)

Why two floats 5.0-3.0 =2.0 returns an integer, while 5.9-3.9=2.0 does not?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: crucially, `5.9-3.9 != 2.0`. `5.9-3.9 == 2.0000000000000004`